# Как уменьшить размер клавиатуры в Android приложении?

Tags: android, kotlin

Как уменьшить размер клавиатуры в Android приложении?

Comment: что за размер - высота или ширина?

Comment: Можно. (8 символов)

Comment: По идее - никак. Клавиатура не является частью приложения, но является частью системы. Если в API этого системного компонента нет возможности её уменьшить, то и сделать этого нельзя. А такого в API, вроде, как раз и нет.

Comment: Высоту надо уменьшить